# Какая логика в игре Pao Pao

Tags: c#, алгоритм, unity3d

Пишу игру pao pao на c# в Unity.
Не могу правильно прописать логику, алгоритм действий в коде, чтобы все верно и нормально работало. Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно использовать в коде, каким образом построить алгоритм игры, ходы игрока.

Comment: Стоит привести код и показать что не выходит. Или задать более конкретный вопрос

Comment: Ну допустим, как написать, что использовать, чтобы от одного объекта к другому проводилась линия, если игрок сделал правильный ход. Unity 2d.

Comment: LIneRenderer вам в этом поможет

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html

Comment: Я нашел про LineRenderer, да. Но проблема в том, что линия должна рисоваться динамически, с разным количеством точек для поворотов, поворот может быть в любом месте, и начало линии может быть в любом месте, начало линии зависит от клика игрока по ячейке. (кнопки)

Comment: создавайте разные LineRenderer.  Передавайте в них столько точек сколько нужно

Comment: вы можете на примере просто кода показать, как написать кусочек с этим методом? Понимаю логику работы метода, так я и думал приблизительно, но не могу додуматься как в коде это реализовать.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/264189/

Answer (score 1):

```
lineRenderer.SetPositions(pointsArray);
```

Где `pointsArray` это массив координат типа Vector3

`lineRenderer.positionCount` задаете количество отрезков. К примеру вот так можно нарисовать круг

```
    const int POINTS_COUNT = 361;
    Vector3[] pointsArray = new Vector3[POINTS_COUNT];
    lineRenderer.positionCount = POINTS_COUNT;
    for (int i = 0; i < POINTS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        float curSegment = Mathf.Deg2Rad * (i * 360f / POINTS_COUNT);
        pointsArray[i] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(curSegment) * 10, 0, Mathf.Cos(curSegment) * 10);
    }

    lineRenderer.SetPositions(pointsArray);
```

Просто передавая координаты следующих отрезков